# Change workbench moderation state with VBO does not work properly

Tags: 7, views, workbench, actions

I have two workbench moderation states `draft` and `publihsed`

When I try to change the state of a node from `draft` to `published` using VBO's `set moderation state` action, It actually republish the `published` revision. While it should publish the draft revision.

[image]

In the screenshot, it move the `draft` to `published` with revision `4` and that should be the published revision. But it is pointing to the revision 3 that this is the published revision.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Any hint where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch in https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation/issues/3160301#comment-13758806 fixes the issue.